# What determines whether or not I get experience with each blow I land on a zombie?

Tags: dead-island

For want of a weapon, I have been roaming around the island beating zombies to death (well, more death) with my bare fists. I've noticed while doing this that sometimes when I attack a certain zombie, I will gain some experience (usually 7 XP) with each attack I land on that same zombie, along with the bonus I get for breaking it. This only seems to happen with certain zombies, and it doesn't seem to be dependent on whether or not I'm attacking with an actual weapon or going melee. What determines whether or not a zombie will give me experience each time I hit it?

If it makes a difference, I'm playing Sam B., the rapper. He is a true bro.

Comment: I noticed that Curb Stomp will always give 7 exp, as well as breaks...I believe the 7xp you are referring to IS a break, I occasionally got the same thing, but then realized it was a break that I had just not realized

Answer (score 5):

There are three different kinds of bonus experience in Dead Island.

The first is bonus experience from breaking limbs. This is possible via blunt weapons and fists.

The second is bonus experience from cutting limbs. This is possible via sharp weapons.

The third, and last, is bonus experience from head-stomping fallen zombies.

Additionally, this bonus experience is scaled based on the level of the zombie, and is also affected by some skills in the characters skill trees.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but I think you get bonus experience when attacking the "best" spots to attack a certain zombie. Only some zombies can give bonus exp, and only for specific things. Like when facing a thug, every time you hit his arms you'll get bonus exp, and when facing a walker/infected, you get 7 bonus exp for doing a curb stomp. You may also get bonus exp from breaking limbs. I'll need to do a bit more testing to confirm this. Attacking a ram on the back does not grant bonus exp, presumably because apart from explosives you can't harm ram's unless you attack their back.

Comment: You still get 7xp from curb stomping special infected..And I believe "best" spot would always be head. For example, it's better to aim at thug's legs then at head, but this doesn't grant any experience. Legs don't break, unfortunately, so that could be part of the reason you don't get exp.

Comment: @Domocus, Yeah I realise you get 7 exp for curb stomping special infected as well, but really the only one I've come across that you can even knock over is infected, and they're basically the same as walkers. Also, it possibly is just limbs that can break that will grant bonus exp.

Comment: @MrSmooth I knocked over a vomiter last night.  I had the option for Sam B.'s finishing stomp to the head, but unfortunately the game glitched and the vomiter fell through the floor (I did get the experience for killing it a few seconds later) before I could check for bonus exp.

Answer (score 0):

Zombies also have levels (not worked how to see them yet, but there referenced in some skills), I assume like most RPG type games you get more XP from higher level enemies.